# make LaTeX draw a \hline between each line in tabular without using \hline?

Tags: latex

Is there any obvious or pretty way to have LaTeX automatically put a \hline between each line in a table without having to put a \hline between each line?

I thought about creating a command like:

```
\newcommand{\EOL}{\\ \hline}
```

But then I will get non-standard looking tables like this:

```
3 & 2 & 1 \EOL
1 & 2 & 3 \EOL
```

Is there a way such that my table bodies could look like:

```
3 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
```

And yet still get the hlines?

Comment: Not an answer exactly, but [Ed Tufte would recommend *against* doing that](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/The-Visual-Display-of-Quantitative-Information/Edward-R-Tufte/e/9780961392147): most of the time it clutters up the visual field and impairs rather than improves the readability.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about LaTeX.

Comment: There is now a very easy solution: You could use the `hlines` option from the `tabularray` package

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\catcode`@=11
\let \savecr \@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\savecr\hline}
\catcode`@=12

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3\\ 
4 & 5 & 6\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work in full generality; see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130631/4427 for an example why it doesn't.

Comment: Great ! It save my day. i just had to replace `tabularcr` by `arraycr`